# How does forking your Heroku production database (postgresql) impact performance?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm planning to regularly --fork my production Heroku Postgres instance to a staging application.  My question is, is this bad from a performance standpoint?  What impact will this have (if any) on my production performance?

I thought about --forking the follower of my production DB instead, but I consistently get this error when trying to do that.

```
 !    You cannot fork a follower. The database you are attempting to fork is still too new. Please try again later.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fork of your production database should have no to little impact on your production database. Followers do incur some overhead for maintaining the connections, but it is very minimal.

To create a fork you must fork from your production database. You may also take an existing follower and detach it from the main database (which results in a fork).

Comment: Hadn't thought of breaking the follower.  Although, I think I will just stick with forking production and leave it at that.

Comment: Please see my note below.  This doesn't impact the production db, but it does affect the production application!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that creating a fork does restart your application, so take care if running this on production!  Output from the fork creation:

`postgresql... is being created in the background. The app will restart when complete...`

Comment: It restarts the app it's attaching TO, right?  E.g. if you fork a production database but attach it to a staging app, it's the staging app that gets the new ENV and thus restarts... is my understanding correct?